# The Export function with Json do not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1, closedxml

Goal:
Export to Excel based on the selected row from the table.

Problem:
The CloseXML don't want to export to excel when I have executed the code using json.
What part of the code am I missing?

Info:
*Using VS 2019 with asp.net core mvc
*Using CloseXML for exporting to excel

Thank you!

---

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Post</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="" class="datadata" name="scales" value="a" checked></td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="" class="datadata" name="scales" value="b" checked></td>
            <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="" class="datadata" name="scales" value="c" checked></td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


@Html.ActionLink("Filter", "DownloadExcelDocument", "Home")

<button id="run" class="dd">Run</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".dd").click(function () {

            var id = document.getElementsByClassName("datadata");

            var defaultConstructorArray = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {

                if (id[i].checked === true) {
                    defaultConstructorArray.push(id[i].value);
                }
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveExceptions", "Home")',
                data: { 'ids': defaultConstructorArray },
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function () {
                    alert("test");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("jqXHR:" + jqXHR.status + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

---

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication3.Models;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult DownloadExcelDocument()
        {
            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            string fileName = "asdf.xlsx";

            using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                IXLWorksheet worksheet =
                workbook.Worksheets.Add("Authors");
                worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Id";
                worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value = "FirstName";
                worksheet.Cell(1, 3).Value = "LastName";

                worksheet.Cell(2, 1).Value = "a";
                worksheet.Cell(2, 2).Value = "a";
                worksheet.Cell(2, 3).Value = "a";

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                    var content = stream.ToArray();
                    return File(content, contentType, fileName);
                }
            }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SaveExceptions(string[] ids)   //ids has no data, nulls
        {


            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            string fileName = "asdf.xlsx";

            using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                IXLWorksheet worksheet =
                workbook.Worksheets.Add("Authors");
                worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Id";
                worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value = "FirstName";
                worksheet.Cell(1, 3).Value = "LastName";

                worksheet.Cell(2, 1).Value = "a";
                worksheet.Cell(2, 2).Value = "a";
                worksheet.Cell(2, 3).Value = "a";

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                    var content = stream.ToArray();
                    return File(content, contentType, fileName);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use Ajax. In your success function, the data parameter is the file data. JavaScript can not save this as a file.

You can use form submission.

Change the checkbox name to `ids`.

```
<form asp-action="SaveExceptions">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Post</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="" class="datadata" name="ids" value="a" checked></td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="" class="datadata" name="ids" value="b" checked></td>
            <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="" class="datadata" name="ids" value="c" checked></td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Run"/>
</form>
```

Test result.

[image]

Comment: I have an another question. What is the name of the  tool that you use in order to display the video as a animated gif (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgPBL.gif)?

Comment: It's `ScreenToGif`